# Application class not found in Android after using ProGuard

Tags: android, exception, proguard

My application worked well, without any errors, so far. But lately I've began using ProGuard to obfuscate the code now I see the following error report in the Google Play developer console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application MYPACKAGE.MyApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MYPACKAGE.MyApp
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:482)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3950)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MYPACKAGE.MyApp
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:945)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:477)
```

`MyApp` is the custom application class, obviously. There's only one error report on that issue so far, although there are 10,000+ active installations. Does that mean I shouldn't bother with that problem or could it be a serious issue? How can I resolve this?

Comment: If installing this app doesn't crash on your own devices I wouldn't bother too much on the issue.

Comment: But how can this happen? Either ProGuard destroys the application by obfuscating the class names or not - how can this be device-dependent?

Comment: AFAIK it really can't - or should not be the case at least. Thou personally I didn't pay too much attention on this assuming the app works ok on my own devices. From the error it seems Application class name didn't get obfuscated anyway so adding ``-keep`` for obfuscator does no change anyway.

Comment: So it's probably a low-cost device with some "broken" Android and I needn't care?

Comment: My guess would be "broken" Android, let it be some low-cost device or someone experimenting with custom ROMs.

Comment: Thank you, so I won't care :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try add this lines:

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
```

to **proguard.cfg** file

Comment: Thank you! Do I have to do the same for `BroadcastReceiver`s, `IntentService`s and custom classes?

Comment: Is this the same as proguard-project.txt file in my Android project?

Answer (score 4):

ProGuard simply replaces class names by obfuscated class names. If the processed code works on one device (or 10,000+ devices), it should work on all devices.

Moreover, if you disassemble the processed application, you'll see that mypackage.MyApp is still there, with its original name. The default integration of ProGuard in the Android build takes care of keeping activities, services, etc, without any need for additional -keep options.

In short, this is some sort of fluke, most probably unrelated to obfuscation. Simply reinstalling the application may help.

Comment: Thank you! But how can such a "fluke" happen? Either the application class name is obfuscated or not. And if it is not obfuscated (as it must be the case here), this exception can't be thrown, normally, can it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your class names are missing in proguard's obfuscation configuration. Add the following to your `proguard.cfg` with the missing class names.

```
-keep public class your_missing_class_full_name
```

Comment: Thank you :) Does `your_missing_class_full_name` include the package name or just `MainActivity`, for example? Is this only so that the class name is not obfuscated or does it mean that the whole class code is not obfuscated?

Comment: Put the full class name including package name. I think it will only keep the class name safe after obfuscation, but if you want the class members too then you need to go with something like `keepclasseswithmembers`